# Squid configuration for proxy server

Tags: linux, squid

I have a server with 10 ip's that I want to give access to some friends via authentication but I'm stuck on squid's config file.

Let's say I have these ip's available on my server:

- 212.77.23.10
- 212.77.1.10
- 68.44.82.112

And I want to allocate each one of them to a different user like so:

- 212.77.23.10 goes to user manilodisan using password 123456
- 212.77.1.10 goes to user manilodisan1 using password 123456
- 68.44.82.112 goes to user manilodisan2 using password 123456

I managed to add the passwords and authentication works ok but how do I do to restrict one user to one of the available ip's?

I have a basic setup from different bits I found over the internet but nothing seems to work. Here's my squid.conf (all comments are removed to make it lighter):

```
acl ip1 myip 212.77.23.10
acl ip2 myip 212.77.1.10
tcp_outgoing_address 212.77.23.10 ip1
tcp_outgoing_address 212.77.1.10 ip2
http_port 8888
visible_hostname weezie

auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth /etc/squid/squid-passwd
acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow ncsa_users 

acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8
acl SSL_ports port 443  # https
acl SSL_ports port 563  # snews
acl SSL_ports port 873  # rsync
acl Safe_ports port 80  # http
acl Safe_ports port 21  # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443  # https
acl Safe_ports port 70  # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210  # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280  # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488  # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591  # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777  # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 631  # cups
acl Safe_ports port 873  # rsync
acl Safe_ports port 901  # SWAT
acl purge method PURGE
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access allow purge localhost
http_access deny purge
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
icp_access allow all
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log squid
acl QUERY urlpath_regex cgi-bin \?
cache deny QUERY

refresh_pattern ^ftp:  1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern .  0 20% 4320

acl apache rep_header Server ^Apache
broken_vary_encoding allow apache

extension_methods REPORT MERGE MKACTIVITY CHECKOUT

hosts_file /etc/hosts

forwarded_for off

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following

```
acl manilodisan proxy_auth manilodisan
acl manilodisan1 proxy_auth manilodisan1
http_access allow ip1 manilodisan
http_access allow ip2 manilodisan1
```